# How can I format a MYSQL date using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a MYSQL date and consists of: 2011-09-10

How do I make this date look like: August 12, 2011  using javascript?

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+format+date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with creating a new Date Object:

```
var d = new Date('2011-09-10');
```

And then you can use these properties to format it:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to respect the user's local timezone?  If so, then use MySQL's TIME_TO_SEC() function to get the seconds-since-epoch value and multiply it by 1000 to get ms:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(datefield) * 1000, ... FROM ...
```

Then in JavaScript, pass that to the constructor for date:

```
var myDate = new Date(msSinceEpoch);
```

Then you can format it as you see fit:

```
var months = {0: "Jan", 1: "Feb", 2: "Mar", ...}
var formatted = months[myDate.getMonth()] + " " + myDate.getDate() + ", " + myDate.getFullYear();
document.write("The current date is: " + formatted);
```

There are also libraries available to help you do this more gracefully, such as [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/).

If you don't care about respecting the user's local time zone, you can use the MySQL date formatting functions such as [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("%M %e, %Y", datefield) AS myDate, ... FROM ...
```